# Shor algorithm and schnorr signature in ed25519

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography, ed25519, schnorr-signature

Does the application of Shor's algorithm in any way relate/affect the schnorr signature in ed25519?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are you asking whether Shor's algorithm breaks the Schnorr signatures over Curve25519?
Ed25519 signatures are btw related but distinct from Schnorr signatures.

Comment: Hi Maeher, the answer from Squeamish is exactly on point. thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shor's algorithm can compute discrete logs in elliptic curves and thereby recover the secret scalar from a public Ed25519 key, which you can use to forge signatures of your choice.

So, yes, it affects Ed25519—it completely breaks Ed25519, or it would if you could engineer a quantum computer capable of executing it.

It can also compute discrete logs in finite fields, which you can use to forge traditional finite-field Schnorr signatures.